# For what values of r would the series converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Find the values of r for which $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 3^kr^{2k}$

I understand that the common ratio is 3$r^2$ so I know that it converges if and only if |3$r^2$| is less than 1.

So:

-1 < 3$r^2$ < 1

$-\frac{1}{3}$< $r^2$< $\frac{1}{3}$

And this is where I get stuck.

Any suggestions on how to continue?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Use that
$$
0\le r^2<\frac13 \iff \left(r-\frac1{\sqrt{3}} \right)\left(r+\frac1{\sqrt{3}} \right)<0\iff -\frac1{\sqrt{3}}<r<\frac1{\sqrt{3}}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.  Just recall that if $x^2<x_0^2$, then $|x|<|x_0|$.  In turn, this implies that $-|x_0|<x<|x_0|$.

Here, we have $x^2=3r^2$ and $x_0^2=1$.  Therefore,

$$|\sqrt{3}\,x|<\sqrt{1}\implies |x|<\sqrt{\frac13}\implies -\sqrt{\frac13}<x<\sqrt{\frac13}$$